# Json with spring MVC

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I have problem in spring MVC with JSON  i tried to return  a arraylist from my controller but i could not return it

```
function getCategory() {
    alert("Test"); 
    $.getJSON("getCategoryList.do", { message: "Test Message" }, function(value) {
        alert(value[1]);
        alert("inside Json"); 
        alert(JSON.stringify(value));;
        for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++){

        }

    });

}
```

I check to print the message in my controller its working,but when i try to et the value in my jsp page i could not 
muy controller code is

```
@RequestMapping(value="admin/getCategoryList", method=RequestMethod.GET)public  @ResponseBody ArrayList<String> receiveCategoryList(@RequestParam String message) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add(name);
        arrayList.add("success");
        System.out.println("Inside Method");
        System.out.println(name);
        return arrayList;
    }
```

Could any one help me

Comment: Do you have a Json ViewResolver bean in your context?

Comment: You have in javascript in data parameter with name 'message' but your controller expects parameter with name 'name' and this parameter is required.

Comment: @anad change the name as chalimartines says, also be sure that [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) is in your project's classpath.

Comment: @KhueVu,  ya i have <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">in my dispatcher-servlet

Comment: But if you wanna you Jackson, you need to declare it as your ViewResolver right. Your resolver should be `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView` instead of the default `InternalResourceViewResolver`

Comment: thanks khue-vu, I am very new to spring and json I will try with  ViweResolver

Answer (score 0):

To return json data from spring you need to include jackson jars in your pom  and than you have to just declare

@Responsebody in your method where you returning json data That its , you can than directly use that object in your view ,

I tried it with Angular Its working .

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getTeamManager",method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

public @ResponseBody  List getEmployees (Model model){

```
Employee employee1 =new Employee ();
employee1.setName("Himanshu");
employee1.setState("Haryana ");
employee1.setCountry("India ");

Employee employee2 =new Employee ();
employee2.setName("Vijay");
employee2.setState("Haryana ");
employee2.setCountry("India ");

Employee employee3 =new Employee ();
employee3.setName("Himanshu");
employee3.setState("Haryana ");
employee3.setCountry("India ");

List<Employee> employeeList =new ArrayList<Employee>();

employeeList.add(employee1);
employeeList.add(employee2);
employeeList.add(employee3);


return employeeList;
```

}